# Unsure how to query this data

Tags: c#, mysql

I have some data within a table I am importing into an ERP solution. The data is presented like this:

```
buyer name,order id,shipment item id,sku,quantity shipped, price etc
```

The shipment item ID is a unique value and is the primary key along with the order id.

My problem is this:

I need to locate each distinct order and create a sales order based upon that information.

The issue I am having is:

Each shipment item ID has its own row within the database and a simple

```
while(reader.read()){
     ...logic here...
}
```

will not work as it will attempt to create n amount of sales orders for the same customer.

I need to formate a query that will take each shipment item ID and put its SKU, quantity etc into one row so I can attach it properly but I am unsure how this would work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you are creating sales orders, one per order id, right?  and each sales order will have multiple shipments?  How are you creating the data in the new system - is it an API call or something else?  I think the problem is likely there, not your query.

Comment: We are creating sales order, with multiple shipment items per sales order ID. The API is Amazon's MWS Reports API which splits the data like this unfortunately. I am currently working with the ERP provider to determine if I can do a specific command to continually update each sales order incrementally using a generic query rather then trying to manipulate the database any further. I will post my results when I get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with the ERP software provider which will allow me to use a basic SQL statement and do an update on the any sales order which has a primary key of the order ID. This will allow each corresponding shipment item id to be added to the sales order without having to do extra SQL "massaging" as if the record exists it will update it, otherwise it will create a new one.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a group by clause to deduplicate the rows to get the top level information

SELECT [buyer name], [order id], etc
   FROM   orderTable
   GROUP BY [buyer name], [order id], etc
   WHERE [order id] = 1

then  select all the rows seperately

SELECT  *
   FROM    orderTable
   WHERE   [order id] = 1

Comment: The problem is not grabbing distinct values, as I am able to do that currently as the shipmentitemId is unique, what I need to do is put each unique shipmentitemID within its parent order ID in one line so I can create the sales order without additional processing.    

Unless I misunderstand your answer, this query will select the fields from the order table and and return them if the order ID is "1", and then select the fields where order ID is "1". Unless I were to store the results of each query and then iterate over each one again the results of the first query would be lost.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.